# How do you properly add URL parameters to an AJAX data object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out. My app uses AJAX to hit JSON and retrieve data. I'm filtering `category` and `tag` using the platform's built-in parameter support. So my format (which works) looks like this:

Example (Working):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://blog.squarespace.com/blog", 
  data: {format:"json",tag:"mobile"}, 
  dataType: "json", 
  method: "GET"
}).done(function(data){ console.log(data) });
```

Logged data:

```
Object {website: Object, websiteSettings: Object, collection: Object, template: Object, shoppingCart: Object…}
calendarView: false
collection: Object
empty: false
emptyFolder: false
items: Array[1]
shareButtons: Object
shoppingCart: Object
showCart: false
tagFilter: "mobile"
template: Object
website: Object
websiteSettings: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Above, you can see it retrieved an `items` array because one post exists.

The problem arises when I'm hitting a category/tag that uses multiple words or non-alpha characters.

Example of AJAX request (Not Working):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://blog.squarespace.com/blog", 
  data: {format:"json",tag:"Lee%20and%20Morris"}, 
  dataType: "json", 
  method: "GET"
}).done(function(data){ console.log(data) });

Object {website: Object, websiteSettings: Object, collection: Object, template: Object, shoppingCart: Object…}
calendarView: false
collection: Object
empty: false
emptyFolder: false
shareButtons: Object
shoppingCart: Object
showCart: false
tagFilter: "Lee%20and%20Morris"
template: Object
website: Object
websiteSettings: Object
__proto__: Object
```

You can confirm this location has posts available by simply visiting the URL in the browser at: http://blog.squarespace.com/?format=json&tag=Lee%20and%20Morris

After trying to debug, I've also found that by appending the tag parameter and hitting that URL, it's works as intended.

Example (Working):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://blog.squarespace.com/blog?tag=Lee%20and%20Morris", 
  data: {format:"json"}, 
  dataType: "json", 
  method: "GET"
}).done(function(data){ console.log(data) });

calendarView: false
collection: Object
empty: false
emptyFolder: false
items: Array[1]
shareButtons: Object
shoppingCart: Object
showCart: false
tagFilter: "Lee%20and%20Morris"
template: Object
website: Object
websiteSettings: Object
__proto__: Object
```

So my question is why on earth would this not work when using the `data` object, but otherwise work fine?

Comment: I believe jQuery encodes values by default. What happens if you use `data: {format:"json",tag:"Lee and Morris"}, ` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "sent wrong code"?

Comment: Thanks Felix King it looks like that is the case. I'm checking to see what I have to tweak to fix. But if the string is already encoded, shouldn't that be good enough? I don't quite understand why that would present an issue.

Comment: @jasonbarone: Well, if you double encode the data, then you would tell the server to literally look for `Lee%20and%20Morris` (i.e. including the `%20`!) instead of `Lee and Morris`.

Comment: Makes sense, if you want to throw up an answer I can close this out. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, yes that was the issue. I'm tweaking my app to send up an unencoded string instead. Seems to have taken of it.

Comment: Felix, thanks for providing the answer (productive) in addition to downvoting me (not so productive).

Answer (score 0):

As per Felix King's comment, my issue was due to jQuery encoding the data object strings for you. By simply doing the request using unencoded strings, my issue was solved.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://blog.squarespace.com/blog", 
  data: {format:"json",tag:"Lee and Morris"}, 
  dataType: "json", 
  method: "GET"
}).done(function(data){ console.log(data) });
```